# Как получить класс через TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

Я на сервере в ответ передаю класс вот так:

```
Result message = new Result
{
    Status = "success",
    Obj = "writed"
};


var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result), new Type[] { typeof(OwnerWrite) });
if (stream.CanWrite)
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, message);
}
```

Сам классы:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result {
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OwnerWrite {
    public string Content { get; set;  }
}
```

В клиенте раньше получал строку так:

```
data = new byte[64];

int bytes = 0;
response = "";
while (stream.DataAvailable)
{
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    response += (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
}

Console.WriteLine("Сервер: "+response);
```

Что изменить, чтобы в консоль (в клиенте) вывести `Result.Status`?

Comment: Если вы использовали сериализацию в XML, логично на другом конце попробовать сделать десереализацию... https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Как пример:

```
Result result;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

result = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
Console.WriteLine("Сервер: " + result.Status);
```

Comment: Ничего не высветилось

Comment: @Дмитрий тогда прикрепите недостающий код + то, как вы открываете стрим  на стороне клиента